# Error while deploying Oppty flexi page to higher orgs. ERROR: There is more than one instance identifier with the same name: 'flexipage_richText4'

Tags: deployment, opportunity, flexipages

I have a Opportunity Flexi page and there is no issue while saving my changes in my dev org. But there is an error while I try to deploy the changes to higher orgs.

Error Details: There is more than one instance identifier with the same name: 'flexipage_richText4'

Any suggestions/thoughts?

Comment: That means, you have already one flexi page with same name flexipage_richText4 in the target org. Can you check and confirm?

Answer (score 0):

My immediate guess would be that you have something in production called "flexipage_richText4" already. I have ran into this in the past, and just cloned the page I was trying to deploy, give it a new API name and then it pushes just fine.